# In Perl, how can I join elements of an array after enclosing each element in brackets?

Tags: arrays, perl

I was trying to join elements of a Perl array.

```
@array=('a','b','c','d','e');
$string=join(']',@array);
```

will give me

```
$string="a]b]c]d]e";
```

Is there anyway I can quickly get

```
$string="[a][b][c][d][e]";
```

?

Comment: What, no CPAN answers? Come on people... we can do better than that! :)

Comment: @DVK : You could think of Sinan's answer as the source code to one such module ;)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Another way to do it, using [`sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html).

```
my $str = sprintf '[%s]' x @array, @array;
```

Comment: interesting, please explain why there's @array, @array

Comment: First array - due to being a second operand of `"x"` operator - is evaluated in scalar context and is thus # of elements in the array. The first expression them becomes: "[%s]" repeated N times (the meaning of string "x" operator". The second @array is just a list of parameters passed to sprintf

Answer (score 14):

Here are two options:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = 'a' .. 'e';
my $string = join('', map { "[$_]" } @array);
my $string1 = '[' . join('][', @array) . ']';
```

Comment: +1.  I will respectfully disagree with Sinan Ünür.  This has the best-written solution posted so far, namely the join on "" of a mapped array.  This is clearly distinct from the previous solution using qq|@{[..]}|.

Comment: I like the join/map solution.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps:

```
{
  local $" = "][";
  my @array = qw/a b c d e/;
  print "[@array]";
}
```

Although you should probably just:

```
print "[" . join("][", @array) . "]";
```

Happy coding :-)

Comment: Minor correction: The correct syntax would be: `print "[" . join("][", @array) . "]";`

Comment: @steinar Thanks for the correction -- switching between languages messed with my brain.

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

local $" = '';
my $x = qq|@{[ map "[$_]", qw(a b c d e) ]}|;
```

You can also generalize a little:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

my @array = 'a' .. 'e';

print decorate_join(make_decorator('[', ']'), \@array), "\n";

sub decorate_join {
    my ($decorator, $array) = @_;
    return join '' => map $decorator->($_), @$array;
}

sub make_decorator {
    my ($left, $right) = @_;
    return sub { sprintf "%s%s%s", $left, $_[0], $right };
}
```

Comment: @Sinan Ünür: Clearly you're doing something right, given your reputation on this site.  However, do you really think this is a good solution to give someone who's clearly a new Perl programmer?  Your solution uses a local predefined variable (that's not even scoped!), qq with nonstandard delimiters, embedded lists, anonymous arrays, and map.

Comment: Well, now you have string auto-increment, array references, anonymous subs (and thus closures), => instead of a comma, and sprintf.  I assume you're just doing this for your own amusement at this point! (PS.  There's no harm in that; it just doesn't help the OP.)

Comment: @A.Rex: Relax. Have some fun. The question has already been answered adequately.

Comment: I'm glad I understood you correctly in the end!  Your first solution just wasn't obvious enough to me, sorry; the second definitely helped.  Take care.

Comment: Lots of people write `join STRING => LIST`; it's not all that weird.

Comment: @A. Rex, @Sinan - This is showing someone that Perl is not boring while illustrating TMTOWTDI :) +1