# Merging variables on Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, list, merge

I'm very new to perl. I get a very annoying problem trying to merge two variables.
When I do it on a simple script like:

```
$arg1 = "hello";
$arg2 = " world";
print $arg1.$arg2;
```

It seems to work fine.
But when I'm trying to make it a bit more complex (reading a file into array and then adding the variable), it seems to instead of adding the second variable, it's replacing the first characters of the first variable instead.

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use LWP::Simple;
use Parallel::ForkManager;
use vars qw( $PROG );
( $PROG = $0 ) =~ s/^.*[\/\\]//;
if ( @ARGV == 0 ) {
        print "Usage: ./$PROG [TARGET] [THREADS] [LIST] [TIMEOUT]\n";
    exit;
}
my $host = $ARGV[0];
my $threads = $ARGV[1];
my $weblist = $ARGV[2];
my $timeout = $ARGV[3];
my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new($threads);
alarm($timeout);
open(my $handle, "<", $weblist);
chomp(my @webservers = <$handle>);
close $handle;

repeat:
for $target (@webservers) {
        my $pid = $pm->start and next;
                        print "$target$host\n";
                        get($target.$host);
        $pm->finish;
}
$pm->wait_all_children;
goto repeat;
```

So if the text file (list) would look like this:

```
www.site.com?url=
www.site.net?url=
etc
```

And the host variable is domain.com.
So instead of having something like: `www.site.com?url=domain.com`, I keep having this: `domain.comsite.com?url=`.
It's replacing the first characters of the first variable with the second variable. I can't get my head around it.

Any kind of help would be appreciate as I'm sure I'm just missing a small thing that would make me feel stupid later.

Thanks ahead, have a good day!

Comment: Using `goto` is not a great idea. Use a `while(1)` loop if you want an infinite loop.

Comment: If u searched , maybe this helpful for u : [ join elements][1] , an this :[concatenate variables in perl][2].

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047895/in-perl-how-can-i-join-elements-of-an-array-after-enclosing-each-element-in-bra
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782435/how-to-concatenate-variables-in-perl

Comment: Not sure those links are helpful or relevant to the problem.

Comment: `my @webservers = <$handle>; s/\s+\z// for @webservers;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your input file probably contains the carriage return `\r` character. You can remove it by `s/\r//g`, or convert the input form MSWin to *nix by `dos2unix` or `fromdos`.

Comment: But the `chomp` in the code does that, if all is well.

Comment: @reinierpost: `chomp` removes `\n` on *nix, which is `\x0A`, it doesn't handle `\r` which is `\x0D`.